# Ionic Virtual Scroll not displaying

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to use the Virtual Scroll to display lists of pictures in Ionic 3.

My code in view in as follows:
Pictures

```
 <div *ngIf="picturesByChildIndex && picturesByChild">
  Pictures
  <div *ngFor="let child of picturesByChildIndex; index as childIndex">
    <div [virtualScroll]="picturesByChild[childIndex]" [approxItemHeight]="pictureSize + 'px'" [approxItemWidth]="pictureSize + 'px'" [bufferRatio]="5">
      <div class="">
        {{picturesByChild[childIndex] | json}}
      </div>
      <div *virtualItem="let pictureEntity" class="image-container"
      [style.width]="pictureSize + 'px'" [style.height]="pictureSize + 'px'"
      (click)="onOpenPicture(pictureEntity?.$key, $event)">
      <ion-img [src]="pictureEntity?.thumb" class="image" tappable></ion-img>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Objects in my controller:

```
picturesByChildIndex ["child2", "child1", "-Kr2WLq5XxjnrDzAizTF"]
picturesByChild (3) [Array(3), Array(4), Array(3)]
picturesByChild[0] "child2"
  insertTimestamp: 1500362912
  thumb: "https://storage.googleapis.com/..."
  $exists: ƒ ()
  $key: "-KpJaJATCnHtaSU1Pjqn"
```

And finally, `pictureSize` is `125`

Any idea why pictures are not displayed ? I see the text `Pictures` only, nothing else

Comment: I not sure that this is a solution in my case because anything that is being put in the `virtualItem` is not displayed event text.

Comment: From what I can see on the internet, `virtualScroll` in a `*ngFor` is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as you and the solution was pretty simple: I had to remove the virtualScroll from the *ngIf block (or ngFor in your case).

Apparently the condition was interacting with the load of the scroll.

I placed it out of the condition and used a workaround to reenable the condition on the array I was passing to the virtualscroll.

I hope it helps someone that get here with the same problem